# How to set default value for row labels in pivot table using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working with excel reports. I need to generate pivot table with some particular field as default value in row labels rather selecting all fields. I am using apache POI.

[This what I am getting automatically when I load excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/338lU.png)

[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YALU.png)

```
AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:D5", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
        CellReference position = new CellReference(10,0);

         XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet1.createPivotTable(source, position,wb.getSheet("1econtent"));

         pivotTable.addReportFilter(2);
         pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);

         pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
         pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1,"% of value");

         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(1).setShowDataAs(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STShowDataAs.PERCENT_OF_COL);
         DataFormat dataformat = wb.createDataFormat();
         short numFmtId = dataformat.getFormat("0.00%");
         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(1).setNumFmtId(numFmtId); 
         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("PivotStyleMedium10");
```

I tried many ways but I didn't find any answer.

Comment: So you basically want to filter the names and only display a given value?

Comment: yes @XtremeBaumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pivot table creation in `apache poi` is only rudimentary until now.

`Apache poi` adds as much pivot field items of type "default" (`<item t="default"/>`)  as rows are in the data source. This is because they don't want have a look at the data and so they are assuming as much different values as rows are in the data source. This is fine because Excel will rebuild its pivot cache while opening.

But if we want preselect items, then this is not fine. Then we must know what items there are that can be preselected.

So we need at least as much items as we want preselect being numbered items: `<item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/>...`. And we must build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items.

To fulfill that requirement we need determine the unique labels all over the rows in data source. Then for each unique label take the item as numbered item. Then build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items. Then set all not wanted items hidden.

Let's have a complete example which creates what you have shown in your question's pictures. Your code in your question is incomplete, so I had must predict what data you have as data source. Please try avoiding that in further questions and always provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Else you will not get answers further.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreatePivotTablePercentAndFilter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pivottable.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot");
   Sheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

   setCellData(dataSheet);

   AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A1:D5", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
   
   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)pivotSheet).createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A4"), dataSheet);

   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
 
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1,"% of value");

   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(1).setShowDataAs(
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STShowDataAs.PERCENT_OF_COL);
   DataFormat dataformat = workbook.createDataFormat();
   short numFmtId = dataformat.getFormat("0.00%");
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(1).setNumFmtId(numFmtId);

   /*   
   Apache poi adds 5 pivot field items of type "default" (<item t="default"/>) for each row label here. 
   This is because there are 5 rows (A1:D5) and, because they don't want have a look at the data, 
   they are assuming max 5 different values. 
   This is fine because Excel will rebuild its pivot cache while opening. 

   But if we want preselect items, then this is not fine. Then we must know what items there are that can be preselected.

   So we need at least as much items as we want preselect being numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/>...
   And we must build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items.

   To fulfill that we need determine the unique labels in column. 
   Then for each unique label take the item as numbered item. 
   Then build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items. 
   Then set all not wanted items hidden.
   */

   //determine unique labels in column 0
   java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
    uniqueItems.add(dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(areaReference.getFirstCell().getCol()).getStringCellValue());
   }
   System.out.println(uniqueItems);
   int i = 0;
   for (String item : uniqueItems) {
    //take the items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/>
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
    //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
    //<sharedItems><s v="Jack"/><s v="Jane"/><s v="Tarzan"/><s v="Terk"/></sharedItems>
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(0)
    .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
    i++;
   }

   //Now we can predefinite a filter.
   //If the need is selecting multiple items, first MultipleItemSelectionAllowed needs to be set.
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).setMultipleItemSelectionAllowed(true);
   //Then set H(idden) true for all items which not shall be selected. All except "Jane" in this case.
   i = 0;
   for (String item : uniqueItems) {
    if (!"Jane".equals(item))
     pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().getItemArray(i).setH(true);
    i++;
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }

 static void setCellData(Sheet sheet) {
  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
   new Object[]{"Names", "Values", "ColC", "ColD"},
   new Object[]{"Jane", 10d, "?", "?"},
   new Object[]{"Tarzan", 5d, "?", "?"},
   new Object[]{"Terk", 10d, "?", "?"},
   new Object[]{"Jack", 10d, "?", "?"}
  };
  for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   Object[] rowData = data[r];
   for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c);
    if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
     cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
    } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
     cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```