# Create filter on Integer column (with default values selected) while creating pivot table using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create filter on third field which is not included in Rows/Columns and that field is Integer. For String I am able to create it and it's working fine but for Integer it's not working.

Below is the sample code which referred from one of the post to create a sample for Integer values:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;


class PivotIntegerFilter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
         FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("D:\\user\\temp\\pivottable.xlsx")) {

        Sheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot");
        Sheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

        setCellData(dataSheet, workbook);

        AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A1:E5", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet) pivotSheet).createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A4"), dataSheet);

        pivotTable.addReportFilter(1);

        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2);
 
        DataFormat dataformat = workbook.createDataFormat();
        short numFmtId = dataformat.getFormat("0");
        pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(1).setNumFmtId(numFmtId);

        java.util.TreeSet<Integer> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<Integer>();
        for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow() + 1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow() + 1; r++) {
            uniqueItems.add((int) dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
        }
        int i = 0;

        short numFmtId1 = dataformat.getFormat("0");
        pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).setNumFmtId(numFmtId1);
        for (Integer item : uniqueItems) {
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();

            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long) i);

            int y = item.intValue();
            //CTNumber c = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems().addNewN();
            //c.set(XmlObject.Factory.newValue(Integer.toString((int) y)));
            pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(Integer.toString(y));
            if (!"3".equals(item.toString())) {
                pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).getItems().getItemArray(i).setH(true);
            }
            // pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).setNumFmtId(numFmtId1);
            i++;
        }

        pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).setMultipleItemSelectionAllowed(true);
        workbook.write(fileout);
    }
}

static void setCellData(Sheet sheet, Workbook workbook) {
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;
    Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
            new Object[]{"PARTY", "SNO", "VOTES", "Total Count", "Total Absent"},
            new Object[]{"REPUBLICAN", 1, 10d, "?", "?"},
            new Object[]{"DEMOCRAT", 3, 5d, "?", "?"},
            new Object[]{"AMERICAN INDEP", 3, 10d, "?", "?"},
            new Object[]{"DECLINED", 2, 10d, "?", "?"}
    };
    for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
        row = (XSSFRow) sheet.createRow(r);
        Object[] rowData = data[r];
        for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
            cell = row.createCell(c);
            if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
                cell.setCellValue((String) rowData[c]);
            } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
                cell.setCellValue((Double) rowData[c]);
            } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Integer) {
                cell.setCellValue((int) rowData[c]);
                DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
                CellStyle integerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                integerCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0"));
                cell.setCellStyle(integerCellStyle);
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create filter on SNO field which is not included in rows, columns or values. If someone can help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example seems to be adopted from [How to set default value for row labels in pivot table using poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119428/how-to-set-default-value-for-row-labels-in-pivot-table-using-poi/58137844#58137844). There my answer explains the basics.

The difference is that the example there uses text items to filter. Your example needs numeric items to filter.

For text items `sharedItems` in `pivotCacheDefinition` - `cacheFields` - `cacheField` are `s`-items.

For numeric items `sharedItems` in `pivotCacheDefinition` - `cacheFields` - `cacheField` are `n`-items. But while `sharedItems` having `s`-items don't need furthrt settings, `sharedItems` having `n`-items need further settings about the number type. For example:

```
<sharedItems containsSemiMixedTypes="false" containsString="false" containsNumber="true" containsInteger="true">
 <n v="1"/>
 <n v="2"/>
 <n v="3"/>
</sharedItems>
```

Code differences:

For text items:

```
for (String item : uniqueItems) {
 ...
 pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(0)
  .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
 ...
}
```

For numeric items:

```
for (Integer item : uniqueItems) {
 ...
 pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
  .setContainsSemiMixedTypes(false);
 pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
  .setContainsString(false);
 pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
  .setContainsNumber(true);
 pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
  .setContainsInteger(true);
 pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
  .addNewN().setV(item);
 ...
}
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class PivotIntegerFilter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./pivottable.xlsx")) {

   Sheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot");
   Sheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

   setCellData(dataSheet, workbook);

   AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A1:E5", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet) pivotSheet).createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A4"), dataSheet);
    
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);

   pivotTable.addReportFilter(1);

   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2);

   java.util.TreeSet<Integer> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<Integer>();
   for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow() + 1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow() + 1; r++) {
    uniqueItems.add((int) dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
   }
    
   int i = 0;
   for (Integer item : uniqueItems) {
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long) i);

    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
     .setContainsSemiMixedTypes(false);
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
     .setContainsString(false);
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
     .setContainsNumber(true);
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
     .setContainsInteger(true);
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(1).getSharedItems()
     .addNewN().setV(item);
            
    if (!(item == 3)) {
     pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).getItems().getItemArray(i).setH(true);
    }
        
     i++;
   }

   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(1).setMultipleItemSelectionAllowed(true);
    
   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }

 static void setCellData(Sheet sheet, Workbook workbook) {
  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
   new Object[]{"PARTY", "SNO", "VOTES", "Total Count", "Total Absent"},
   new Object[]{"REPUBLICAN", 1, 10d, "?", "?"},
   new Object[]{"DEMOCRAT", 3, 5d, "?", "?"},
   new Object[]{"AMERICAN INDEP", 3, 10d, "?", "?"},
   new Object[]{"DECLINED", 2, 10d, "?", "?"}
  };
  for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   Object[] rowData = data[r];
   for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c);
    if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
     cell.setCellValue((String) rowData[c]);
    } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
     cell.setCellValue((Double) rowData[c]);
    } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Integer) {
     cell.setCellValue((Integer) rowData[c]);
     DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
     CellStyle integerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
     integerCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0"));
     cell.setCellStyle(integerCellStyle);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Oh I tried before adding setContainsInteger but it didn't work but with that we need to add other also got it. Thanks.